# How can I set the indent of the second line in TOC, LOT, LOF, and Bibliography?

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, indentation

I use `article` document class. I would like to set the indent of the second line in TOC, LOF, LOT, and Bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
{
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}
    \listoffigures
}
\newpage

\begin{figure}[!ht]
     \includegraphics{example-image-a}
     \caption{Blablabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But I can't set the second line indent or hanging indent whatever you called.

For example:

```
                   LIST OF FIGURES

Figure 2.1. BlaBla BlaBla  BlaBla BlaBla BlaBla BlaBla
BlaBla BlaBla BlaBla BlaBla BlaBla

Figure 2.1. BlaBla BlaBla  BlaBla BlaBla BlaBla BlaBla
            BlaBla BlaBla BlaBla BlaBla BlaBla
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This seems document class dependent. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}`.

Comment: The default indentation is what you need.

Comment: Having the prefix string "Figure" before the figure number in the List of Figures is *non-standard*. Please tell us which document class you employ and what you've tried so far in terms of modifying the Table of Contents, the List of Figures, and the List of Tables in order to meet your formatting requirements.. In the Table of Contents, do you intend to prefix chapter-level entries with the string "Chapter", section-level entries with the string "Section", etc? What about the List of Tables: Should each entry be prefixed with the string "Table"? Please be **very specific**.

Comment: And please also explain the link between the ToC/LoF/LoT group and the formatted bibliography. Specifically, what are your formatting needs for the bibliography? The reason I ask is that, in a LaTeX document, the bibliography is generated by a completely separate process that's entirely, utterly unrelated to the creation of the ToC, the LoF, and the LoT.

Comment: I have edited the post. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @SametMemiş Please show an MWE not a code snippet. Off topic: no need to use `{` after `\begin{}` and `}` before `\end{}`.

Comment: Sorry I am new in this platform. I try to understand what you tell me. I hope I got it right. I tried to write a minimal working example. Thanks.

Comment: Your MWE looks good. The only problem is the file `Sekil1` which we do not have. You can use `example-image-duck` instead, which should be included in any recent LaTeX distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Screwing up `\numberline` is no good idea -- rather use the `tocloft` package and change the macro `\cftfigpresnum` and the `\cftfignumwidth` length.

`\cftfigpresnum` holds any content that should be printed before the 'section number', i.e. the figure number here, whereas `\cftfignumwidth` is increased in this case to give enough width to add the figure name, which is stored in `\figurename.

The relevant macros for the ToC and LoT are `\cftchappresnum`, (chapter, etc. for more see the `tocloft` manual) and `\cfttabpresnum` and the `\cftchapnumwidth` and `\cfttabnumwidth`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\figurename~}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{30pt}

\begin{document}
%{
%    \let\oldnumberline\numberline
%    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}
%    \listoffigures
%}
\listoffigures

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
     \includegraphics{example-image-a}
     \caption{Blablabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla blablabla bla blabla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Although these codes are working in MWE, when I use your codes, "Figure" disappear and only "1" appear in my original file.

Comment: @SametMemiş: Well, your original file seems to set up in a very strange manner than.